# Convert import() to synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to convert all of my node `require()`s into the `import()` statements, however, those are async and I'm having a bit of trouble.

Right now I have:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

const paths = fs.readdirSync('./src/modules').map(path => './modules/' + path.slice(0, path.length - 3));

const classes = [];

paths.forEach(path => {
    let bClass = require(path);

    try {
        classes.push(new bClass.default());
    }
    catch (err) {
        //Here for if no default import
    }
});
```

and want to convert that `require(path)` part into an `import()` but still want to keep it synchronous, is that possible? If it is, how would I got about it?

Edit: a little more context. I have a list of modules that we want to import, and we're doing it this way so if something bugs out with one module we can just comment it out / remove it and not have to recode everything else. I just need dynamic synchronous imports without using `require()`.

Comment: You have to use async/await (or then on Promises). You can't make asynchronous code synchronous, you have to await the result.

Comment: `import` in node.js is synchronous (like `require()`).  Not sure what problem you think you have.

Comment: As far as I am aware the ES Module system requires explicit module imports. You cannot import all the modules for a directory. You might be able to make this work with a custom module loader though.

Comment: @Deadron isn't that what the OP is trying to do — iterate through all the modules an explicitly import them?

Comment: If what you're really trying to ask about is "dynamic" or "programmatic" imports, then read this article: http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html

Comment: @Mark_M What I was saying is that ES Modules do not currently support this use case. I did find that there is a Stage 3 proposal that does what I believe the original poster wants https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import  So, if the poster is using babel they could try an implementation of this.

Comment: @R.Gillie `import()` is by definition async, so you can't do what you want. You'll need to refactor your code to handle async import. Using `async/await` this is sometimes very easy to do.

Comment: @Aaron I'm having trouble with this, I've been trying to find out how to do this with async/await all morning but then run into the problem of having to run the  async function sync

Comment: Forgot to edit my comment with @jhpratt but I'm having my previous issue where if I convert it to async/await I now have to run that async function, sync

Comment: Yes, you'd have to have an IIFE. It's best to avoid this design pattern until top-level `await` comes to JS.

Comment: @jhpratt how would I use an IIFE? It doesn't seem that top-level `await` is coming any time soon

Comment: So, why can't you just use `require()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 my buddy who is supervising this whole thing wants to move away from node specific things and want's it to be all commonjs, but it looks like he's going to have to wait for a bit until we get top level `await`

Comment: @R.Gillie - Well, you're using `fs.readdirSync()` right there which is node-specific.  Seems like you need to convince your buddy that it's a bit of a false goal, particularly when `import` doesn't support dynamic loading anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00 we're doing what we can. Common doesn't have a way to read files right now, which is why we're using `fs`, if there ever is a way, we would change it. With the new `import()` he thought it would be possible to remove all the `require()`s. But it turns out there isn't any way right now, so I'll let him know.

Comment: @jfriend00 looks like in Node v12 also dynamic imports are done dynamic - using TypeScript and babel

Comment: `require` is synchronous, so it's not clear why you wouldn't want to use that.  
One situation where `require` cannot be used is when the target to load is an ESM format file.  In that you could convert the ESM module to CJS using rollup.  Then you can `require` it.  However, if the loader is also EMS, then you have to add some extra declarations to enable `require`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently with commonJS. Until there is some synchronous `import()` or top-level await, this cannot be done.

Comment: Not correct, see my answer below.

Comment: Idea of sync and async things is differs only in that SYNC code has "while (true)" and but ASYNC code has Promise.then(). So if you want to make any async code to sync, you have to write this construct
```
let result = undefined; (new Promise()).then(() => (ready = ['any data'])); while (true) { if (ready !== undefined) break; } return result;
```

Answer (score 14):

I found this on the nodejs doc:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

// sibling-module.js is a CommonJS module.
const siblingModule = require('./sibling-module');
```

This allows you to recreate the "require" function in es6+
I've not tested if it works but the doc said that so

Source:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/module.html#module_module_createrequire_filename

Comment: you are wrong, this is finely working. Of course, for it to work, you have to be in a ESM module file (.mjs or type: 'module').

Comment: After trying this recently I can confirm this works.
Thanks very much

Comment: Ok so just to expand further it seems to depend on which runtime is being used
node - doesn't work, complains about not being able to use require for es modules
tsx - does seem to work without complaining
ts-node - might work with the experimentalResolver setting I'm not sure
https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935

I remember asking about this before but got no answers here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72635032/how-to-wait-for-js-promises-to-complete-without-using-then-or-await?noredirect=1#comment128305089_72635032

Answer (score 9):

You can use [deasync](https://github.com/abbr/deasync) or [node-sync](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync) to convert anything, including imports, to be synchronous - without blocking the whole node process.

Here is a plugin I wrote to do that:
[require-esm-in-cjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-esm-in-cjs)

Or you can block the entire process and load the package using `require('child_process').execSync`. This is usually not recommended, but may be OK for compiling a local script, etc.

In addition, CommonJS supports async/await within a function. So in many cases you can do (which is async, but has synchronous function flow)

```
async function main(){
    let mod = await import('my-module')
        .catch(console.log);
    // do something with mod...
    }
main();
```

And, if you are using a ESM module, top level await() is now supported.

Comment: Interesting! The downside here, though, is that the `deasync` dependency is partially implemented in C++ code.

Answer (score 6):

Current versions of Node.js support top-level await behind the flag `--harmony-top-level-await` (Node >= 13.2) or `--experimental-top-level-await` (Node >= 14.3). When Node is launched with either of the flags, an import like

```js
import fs from 'fs';
```

Can be re-written in CommonJS as

```js
const fs = await import('fs');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can still use require() function by using this babel plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node-sync

Answer (score 4):

## [import-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-sync)

I wrote **import-sync** to accomplish this in NodeJS:

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-sync
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync

**import-sync** is a wrapper around the [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) module loader with a few tweaks to enable CJS/ESM imports into both ESM and CJS-based projects (any combination will work).

---

Supposed you have an ES module:

```js
/*
 * esModuleExample.js/esModuleExample.mjs
 */
export const myEsmSumExport = (a, b) => a + b;
```

then, for CJS,

```js
/*
 * index.js/index.cjs
 */
const importSync = require('import-sync');
const { myEsmSumExport } = importSync('./esModuleExample');
```

or, for ESM,

```js
/*
 * index.mjs/index.js with "type": "module" in package.json
 */
import importSync from 'import-sync';
const { myEsmSumExport } = importSync('./esModuleExample');
```

For further examples, see these two answers below:

1. Importing both CJS and ESM simultaneously into an ESM project

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77334536/22324694
2. Importing pure-ESM libraries (e.g. [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch)) into a CJS project

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77329422/22324694

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

There's some comments about it in this github issue - https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/454
Basically doing a require of an esm module.

Outside of [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kaciras/deasync) which uses hacks as a workaround.

There's also [synckit](https://github.com/un-ts/synckit) although that does require the data passed around to be serializable by the Structured clone algorithm

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call `await import(...)` for a list of paths, you can do so by using `Array.reduce()` with a `Promise` as the initial value.

This will allow you to synchronously iterate over a list of promises that call `await import()` internally, like so:

```
const paths = fs.readdirSync(...);

const classes = await paths.reduce(async (acc, path) => {
    const arr = await acc; // This waits for the previous iteration to resolve.
    const mod = await import(path + '/somefile.js');
    arr.push(mod.default);
    return arr;
}, Promise.resolve([])); // Start with an immediately resolved promise
```

> Top level `await` is available since node v14.8  https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.8.0/