# Does module import in JavaScript is synchronous or not?

Tags: javascript, module

When a JavaScript module is imported with the following syntaxe in JavaScript (client side), does it load the module asynchronously?

```
import {myFunction, myVar} from './my_module.js'
```

Does the execution of the main script is stopped until the module is fully loaded or does it runs and load the module at the same time?

I just want to be sure there is no risk at using an imported function or variable just after the import:

```
import {myFunction, myVar} from './my_module.js'
myVar = myFunction(); // Am I sure it is already loaded?
```

Comment: http://calculist.org/blog/2012/03/29/synchronous-module-loading-in-es6/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069002/convert-import-to-synchronous

Comment: since `myfunction` would be "defined" on the very next line if you wanted to use it, what do you infer from that?

Comment: @Tibias, I have some difficulties translating the page linked, but I understand it is synchronous, could you confirm?

Comment: @Jaromanda, I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Fifi - huh? no, it's clear, I'm telling you it is synchronous, the execution waits for the import to finish and the code in the import is parsed and executed - there is no need for clarity ... `Am I sure it is already loaded?` YES

Comment: OK, thank you guys. If you answer the question, i'll upvote.

Comment: The nice thing about ES6 modules is that the browser can start loading dependencies before executing any code.