# How to import ESM modules in a Node.js app at runtime without 'type':'module' or .mjs extension?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I need to develop a nodejs application in which it should be possible to dynamically import ESM modules in a commonJS module during the run time.

1. Without requiring the need to specify `"type":"module"` in package.json file / use *.mjs* extension.
2. Also support importing of ESM module files which in turn import some pure ESM module (example: *node-fetch@3*)
   OR
   Is there some option in the "esm" [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) to also support importing ESM modules that in turn import a pure ESM module(example: *node-fetch@3*)

Here's what I have tried so far:-

1. Using [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)
   This approach works as expected for importing commonjs modules dynamically during run time. But, for importing ESM modules, there is a requirement to mention "type":"module" in package.json / naming the files with ".mjs" extension.
2. Using the [esm npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm).
   This is an old npm package that I found which is able to import ESM modules in commonJS modules dynamically without the need to specify `"type":"module"` in *package.json* file. However, trying to import an ESM module which imports a pure ESM module(example: *node-fetch@3*) fails with this.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR:

```
$ npm install import-sync
```

then

```js
const importSync = require('import-sync');
const yourModule = importSync('./path/to/your/module');
```

---

There is an open [issue (#904)](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/904) for the [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) library about

> Error [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol 'node:' not supported. Expected 'file:'

If we look into the source code of, for example, [index.js in node-fetch version 3](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/8b3320d2a7c07bce4afc6b2bf6c3bbddda85b01f/src/index.js#L9-L13),
you can see that there are imports such as

```js
import http from 'node:http';
import https from 'node:https';
```

which isn't compatible with the esm library.

I'm sure you're aware of this too, the default `require` also doesn't work with node-fetch as described in their CommonJS [documentation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/8b3320d2a7c07bce4afc6b2bf6c3bbddda85b01f/README.md#commonjs):

> node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require().
>
> If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with CommonJS. Critical bug fixes will continue to be published for v2.

---

I had a similar requirement, so I wrote **import-sync**:

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-sync
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync

The library wraps around [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) and will enable you to dynamically import ESM modules in a CommonJS module (or even an ESM module) at runtime, including submodules that leverage pure-esm libraries such as node-fetch.

You can install the library with:

```
npm install import-sync
```

Then use it as follows:

```js
// import importSync from 'import-sync'; // for ESM
const importSync = require('import-sync');

if (someCondition) {
  const someEs6Module = importSync('../../someEs6Module');
  console.log(someEs6Module);
}
```

Specific to node-fetch, here is an example:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "import-sync": "^2.0.4",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```js
const importSync = require('import-sync');

const nodeFetch = importSync('node-fetch');
console.log(nodeFetch);

const myModule = importSync('./myModule');
console.log(myModule);
```

`myModule.js`

```js
import nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';

export const randomVariable = 'helloworld';
```

Running

```bash
node index.js
```

will give the expected results:

[image: VSCode results]

If you decide to add "type": "module" to your `package.json` later down the line, the logic still applies. See this answer here for an example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77334536/22324694

Hope this helps :).